# CURL keeping session with get and post

Tags: php, curl

I have logged in to a website with post and it's OK. When I get this site with GET method everything is ok (returend "Hello, username !" etc) but when I'am trying to send post to this site it's redirecting me to login page. It's seems to curl doesnt send cookie session with post method. How to fix it ?
My code:

```
public function curlInit()
{
    $this->_ch = null;
    $this->_ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->_userAgent);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 25);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies-jar.txt');
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies-jar.txt');
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,  1);
    if ($this->proxy)
    {
        curl_setopt ($this->_ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy);
    }
}
public function getPostSite($url, $data)
{
    $this->curlError = false;

    curl_setopt($this->_ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($this->_ch);
    if (curl_errno($this->_ch))
    {
        $this->curlError = curl_errno($this->_ch);
        return false;
    }
    return $result;
}
public function  getGetSite($url)
{
    curl_setopt($this->_ch,CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($this->_ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Are you calling your `curlInit()` function before calling any of these?

Comment: Yes, only once before all.

Comment: I'm thinking CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER is filling in last page requested rather than url of the form. Try curl_setopt ($this->_ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url_of_form);

Comment: Try first the Developper tools in firefox to check whether the session is created or not.

Comment: Imane Fateh: I run this from console. The page is creating session cookie, I can watch it on developer tools on this site and in cookie file.

Comment: Waygood: doesn't help